# (I don't know how to compare strings) Writing to a file with a while loop

Tags: java, string

my intent for this program was to create a simple program that takes input from the terminal line by line, and stores it into a file in the same fashion, ending when the user inputs "end".

I'm confused about why...
1) the while loop does not end when the user inputs "end"
2) the data is not written to the file (I've checked, it doesn't for whatever reason)

Edit: the answer has been found already! For those just arriving, my while condition should have been !temp.equals("end")

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Type in data and it will be written to a file");
    System.out.println("filename = blah.txt");

    String temp, filename="blah.txt";

    PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

    System.out.println("enter next line... \"end\" to exit");
    temp=in.nextLine();
    while(temp!="end"){
        outfile.println(temp);
        System.out.println("enter next line... \"end\" to exit");
        temp=in.nextLine();
    }

    outfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `equals` instead of

```
temp!="end" // temp.equals("end")
```

Flush the output stream before closing because by default PrintWriter object is created without automatic line flushing. Hence

```
outfile.flush()
```

or when you are creating PrintWriter object then pass [true](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.Writer,%20boolean%29) as second argument like this

```
PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename), true);
```

Comment: Closing the stream also flushes it. Also, autoflushing can have performance effects, although in this case it's not important.

Comment: I agree that autoflushing has additional cost that's why i mentioned about flush method as well. Thanks

Comment: people have mentioned that I should use temp.equals("end"), but why doesn't my method work? It would have been my go-to method in c++, which was my first language. From what I understand, Java was built out of C++.

Comment: == tests for reference equality but you want to test for value equality(actual content of the string) that why use equals()

Comment: @BrentAllard C string comparison would use `strcmp`; C++ happens to overload `==`, but the semantics are different than `strcmp`. Java (deliberately) does not support operator overloading.

Comment: Thanks, Dave and sol!

Answer (score 0):

when checking if 2 strings are equal or not use equals method i.e `temp.equals("end")`
this is the reason your while loop is not ending

Answer (score 0):

The while-loop does not end, because you are comparing reference types to each other, not the values of the `String`s. This means, that

```
while( temp != "end" )
```

Checks if the reference of the `String` stored in `temp` equals the reference of `"end"`. Thus the comparison looks somewhat like

```
java.lang.String@549f9afb != java.lang.String@583dad65
```

which always evaluates to `true`.

In order to compare the values of two `String` objects with each other you need to call `equals` on one `String`. So that in your case one has to write:

```
while ( temp.equals( "end" ) )
```

The `PrintWriter` does not write the received output immediately, but stores it until it is flushed. By activating `autoFlush`, the PrintWriter is flushed after every call to `println`. It can be activated setting the `autoFlush` Parameter of the constructor.

```
PrintWriter outfile = 
    new PrintWriter( new FileWriter( filename ), true );
```